# SQLite Database to Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a requirement, where I have to move data from text into SQLite DB on Android.

One way to do this was to move the text file to asset manager and from there I can insert data into the DB.

Is there any way through which I can insert all the data into the SQlite DB using Desktop app and then just ship the SQLite DB with the android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you.

Prepare the sqllite in desktop and then transfer it over to android

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Have fun:

http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/index.html

Edit:

and then the solution is already on StackOverflow:
[Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Comment: I should I put the DB into the resource folder and when i will open the file form android , how I know where to look for ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data needs to be input, you could also do it from within the application. E.g.

```
 void InsertDepts(SQLiteDatabase db)
     {
         ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(colDeptID, 1);
            cv.put(colDeptName, "Sales");
            db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
            cv.put(colDeptID, 2);
            cv.put(colDeptName, "IT");
            db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
            cv.put(colDeptID, 3);
            cv.put(colDeptName, "HR");
            db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);
            db.insert(deptTable, colDeptID, cv);

     }
```

Comment: Secondly , i have lot of data. I am working on GRE app and it a list of words.

Comment: That would be in your helper class but in your case, it might not be idea if it's a lot of data.